# Loss function and activation function for categorical AND multi-label classification in neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, multi-class, multilabel

I am training a neural network to classify a set of objects into n-labels, each label with m different category. E.g. for n = 5, and m = 3, an example output is [0,2,0,2,1].

I can also transform the output into a 2-D matrix, for example

[0,2,0,2,1] =

[[1,0,0],

[0,0,1],

[1,0,0],

[0,0,1],

[0,1,0]]

Where each row represent a label and each column represent the probability of that label in category 0,1 or 2. But this is where I am stuck.

I understand that for multiclass classification, I should use softmax and categorical cross-entropy as the loss function since the probability should sum up to 1.  For multilabel classification, I should use sigmoids and binary cross entropy since each label has a probability from 0 to 1, independent of other labels. But how about this case? Each row is a multiclass classification and each column is a multilabel classification.

Answer (score 2):

In your scenario, you should treat each label as an independent label prediction and use it in a separate cross entropy, whose results you sum.

In practice, after your second-to-last layer you create five splits, each leading to its own three-neuron sub-layer with a softmax activation, each of which will give you a categorical output on which you apply cross entropy.